# How to get the value of a custom field and make it a variable?

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to access custom field values on an override page on my Joomla 4 site.

I trying to use the FieldsHelper class to access and show the data with this code:

```
<?php echo FieldsHelper::render('com_content.article', 'field.render', array('field' => $this->item->jcfields[19])); ?>
```

I only want to get the values from two specific fields and declare them as variables, but for some reason I can't get the value only.

Comment: if the nominated page does not resolve your specific question, please [edit] your question to explain how the advice on that page fails to satisfy.